# How to return multiple items with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, arrays

Is it possible to return multiple items via AJAX and PHP? I am reading up on it and it seems just like an echo in PHP and responseText via Javascript. Can I return an array of items via PHP and convert it into Javascript or HTML?

Comment: In php, you can do a var_dump to get all the values of an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the data format your PHP response is sending - it sounds like the examples you're seeing are just plain text. The best format in my opinion is JSON which can send an array of multiple results, and even a multi-dimensional array many levels deep.

See [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) in PHP and [JSON examples on jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: Would I have to use JQuery? Right now all my AJAX is just simply javascript.

Comment: Not at all, I just use jQuery for everything :) JSON is native to Javascript so you can [parse JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) very easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JSON format to return multiple values in AJAX: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

You can then decode it in javascript. This function allows you to do it in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/